# angular-materials creates a ton of inline css

Tags: angularjs

I've just added `angular-material` to my project ([source)](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and it works fine, but I've noticed that when I run it, there is an absolute ton of `css` added inline to the `<head>` of my pages.

I mean, isn't this why I am including the `.css` files in my build? Why do I want these inline styles too?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [theming docs](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/Theming/05_under_the_hood)

> At runtime, a function in src/core/services/theming/theming.js called generateThemes() parses $MD_THEME_CSS to generate the `<style>` tags that are added to the `<head>` section of the application. A closure variable called GENERATED is used to keep track of the themes that have had their CSS generated.

Comment: Well. I think that's really stupid - but I guess it cannot be helped. Thank you for pointing that out. I feel dumb for not spotting that myself.